# How to treat a hex as string?

Tags: python

I have some hex number such as `0x61cc1000` and I want to input them to a function which only takes string. I want to treat the hex numbers as strings without any change.

If I use `str()` function it converts it to `int` and *then* treats it as string. But I want to keep the original hex value.

Comment: Can we see some code? It's a little hard to understand exactly what you mean. Where are you getting these hex numbers from?

Comment: A "hex number" doesn't exist. It's an int, represented in base-16 in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using `str`:

```
>>> str(0x61cc1000)
'1640763392'  # int value of the hex number as a string
```

That's because first 0x61cc1000 is evaluated as an `int`, then `str` performed on the resulted `int`.

You want to do:

```
"{0:x}".format(0x61cc1000)
```

Or

```
'{:#x}'.format(0x61cc1000)
```

As already stated in other answer, you can simply:

```
>>> hex(0x61cc1000)
'0x61cc1000'
```

See [6.1.3.1. Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) for details.

Comment: @Bipario I'm glad it helped, see my update if you want to keep `0x`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the hex string representation of any integer, just pass it through the `hex` built-in.

```
>>> n = 0x61cc1000
>>> n
1640763392
>>> hex(n)
'0x61cc1000'
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer we should be using

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have 0x at the beginning you may use `#x` format like this:

```
'{:#x}'.format(74954)
```

Comment: This is great, only improvement is to use `format(74954, '#x')` which is recommended in this case

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't aware of this standalone function.